# How to calculate marker is active or not for 5 min if his lat longs are within 5 meter

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In **mongoDb** , every second , marker lat long position we are saving.

```
{"_id":"5cefaf2ea960706d315f94cf","location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[103.7893009185791,1.23294850317229]},"createdAt":"2019-05-30T10:23:42.456Z","updatedAt":"2019-05-30T10:23:42.456Z"}
```

If the marker is within **5 meter for 5 min**, we need to give alert on UI.

How to figure out this as every second the position of marker is changing ?

Comment: So you only have one marker in the system?

Comment: we have many. For each marker we have to check if it is within 5 meter for 5 min.